# Office.Interop temporary highlight/underline

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

Is there any way in Microsoft.Office.Interop to set temporary highlights, underlines, or styles on ranges, such as for spelling and grammar errors?

I can see methods to inspect existing spelling/grammar errors, but nowhere to create new ones.

I just want to highlight some words from an add-in, without that being saved to the document.

Edit: To be clear, Range.HighlightColorIndex is *not* what I want, as it changes the highlight permanently. I don't want to change the document.

Edit #2: To clarify further, I have done quite a lot of searching about this for weeks on end with various terms of Office, Interop, Word, Underline, Squigglies, Highlight, Style, Decorators, Proofing error, etc.

And read through the Office.Interop docs several times, inspecting promising members like EmphasisMark, GrammaticalErrors, HighlightColorIndex, SpellingErrors, Underline, etc. They are all useless as they modify the document.

And to stave off comments, no it is not good enough to set+unset the style as I don't want to overwrite user's styles. I truly want temporary highlights that in no way affect the document state, exactly like Office's built-in proofing tools do it.

Asking on SO was my last resort, because so far all my research has told me that it is impossible to do what I want via Office.Interop, and I was hoping SO could prove me wrong by pointing out some little known method.

Comment: have you considered a google search on how to highlight text using Office.Interop and C#..

Comment: I have searched quite a lot about that, and can only find ways to add permanent styles to text. No temporary ones.

Comment: try checking out all of these link results.. until you find something that you can use and make it work for your use case.. [Office.Interop](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20highlight%20text%20office.interop)

Comment: You probably mean Range.HighlightColorIndex - this is *not* what I want, as it changes the highlight permanently. I don't want to change the document.

Comment: @MethodMan, to humour you, I've read through the first 100 hits of your specific search. Nothing there is usable, as it causes permanent changes and the document to be considered modified. I'll edit the question again to clarify...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conclusion after conferring with people on several IRC channels is that it's impossible. Office.Interop simply doesn't expose any way to temporarily set styles in a manner similar to the built-in proofing tools.